# What to mask space between panel floor and balcony with?

Tags: windows, floor, finishing

We have put the floors on our own. They're not perfect and we have left too much space 
between the floor and the window. And a standard finishing element like this:

[image: mask]

is too small.

Here are pictures of how it looks:

[image: win1]
[image: win2]

What can we use to mask the space?

Comment: How wide is the gap?

Comment: @bib varies from place to place and from room to room. Up to even 2.0 cm.

Answer (score 2):

You can stack molding.  Perhaps a piece of square stock, then a separate quarter round "shoe molding" as you illustrated.  Be sure to keep your hardwood floor expansion gap intact.

Complex molding is often built up from simpler shapes: once painted you never notice.

Comment: You may even be able to find a piece that is prefinished in a tone similar to your shoe molding.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and used a flat strip of PVC molding from Lowes (see below). You can glue its face to the base of the window if you think it will be attractive enough. You can always rip it to reduce its width with a jigsaw and put that edge down because it will be hidden by the wood molding. Then you can butt the shoe or quarter-round molding up to it. Hopefully the thickness of the two pieces will cover the gap.

[image]